# How to write the following while llop in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the program is :

```
Y=100
while y>0:
    print(y)
    y-=3
```

My teacher said It can be written using for loop but I am not sure how. I want to do this same task using for loop.

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `range()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment by John Gordon says, you can use the `range()` function, where it takes three arguments: start, stop and step. But when we want to go from a larger number to a smaller number, we have to define the *step* (which is an optional argument).

In this case, your step will be -3.
So you do it like so:

```
for y in range(100, 0, -3):
    print(y)
```

Giving you:

```
100
97
94
91
88
.
.
.
```

Some extra help: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp